# System.Runtime.Caching.Cache performance with many items

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, caching

In my website as there are many joins in stored procedure that returns results I want to cache the results for each page and remove and re-add only when there is a change.

Now the question is that in this case there will be about 200000 cached items that for each page I will need to find from cache. I want to know how would be the performance of the cache with many Items?

I know that, I should compare this with the speed of running stored procedure but here what I want to know is the cache speed not its relativity and comparison with getting result from database. In the other words **I want to know how much Increasing the number of cached items would effect the performace?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cache lookups are O(1). So as long as you an actually fit all necessary data in memory the speed of finding item should not change.

Make sure if you have plenty of RAM, using x64 machine/build and indeed run your own performance tests to confirm that your caching works for your cases.

If you want to double-check - source is available on http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Runtime.Caching/System/Caching/MemoryCache.cs

Comment: I have 25GB of free RAM and all my cached items may not use more than 200 MB. I just was concerned about its performance. Thanks a lot for your nice answer.